# Micronaut: How to run a method of a class after micronaut starts up?

Tags: java, kotlin, singleton, micronaut

Let's say I have a simple class written (it is in Kotlin, but this question extends to Java as well):

```
class Bot {
    fun initialize() {
        val client: GatewayDiscordClient =
            DiscordClientBuilder.create("MY-TOKEN")
                .build()
                .login()
                .block()!!

        MajorEvent.createEvents(client)

        client.onDisconnect().block()
    }
}
```

The basic way of running an Micronaut app goes like this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    build()
        .args(*args)
        .packages("com.codenamite")
        .start()
}
```

How can I make the `Bot.initialize()` to be runned at startup? I have experimented with `@Singleton` annotation on the class, and `@PostConstruct` on the `initialize()` method but it doesn't seem to work.

I've tried:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    build()
        .args(*args)
        .packages("com.codenamite")
        .start()
    val bot = Bot()
    bot.initialize()
}
```

It obviously works, but it seems that the `Bot.initialize()` is out of Micronaut's context.

There are plenty of examples how to do it with rest controllers or croned services, but is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Just use @Context

Comment: @IEE1394 how can I achieve that? Should I implement BeanInitializedEventListener? It requires a type, should it be an ServerStartupEvent? I have been trying to use Context, but I cannot achieve anything...

Comment: the main difference between Singleton and Context is, that singleton is lazy loaded. So only on demand. The problem comes, when the class - like your bot - is creating the demand iself. Therefore you must use context, which increase the application statup time, cause your bean is loaded while the app is starting. i could not post a answer here, but look on your other question, i postet there an answer which works for me (also with discord) ;-)

Comment: if you nee the whole example look at this: https://github.com/sambalmueslie/event-organizer/blob/development/src/main/kotlin/de/sambalmueslie/eventorg/discord/DiscordService.kt